# A good practice for renaming properties of a react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, react-hooks, dynamically-generated

I use a react library ex. `react-query`. This library provides a hook `useQuery` ex.

```
const {data, isLoading} = useQuery(['users'], userService.getUsers);
```

My problem is that if I want to use two `useQuery` hooks, in order to avoid having duplicated named variables:

```
data, isLoading
```

I have to do something like this:

```
const users = useQuery(['users'], userService.getUsers);
const products = useQuery(['products'], userService.getProducts);

...
// then use
users.data, users.isLoading
// and
products.data, products.isLoading
...
```

In order to make this logic more consistent, I tried to make my own custom hooks and rename the properties provided by `useQuery` inside so I can access with spread syntax.

```
function useGetUsers(){
    const {data, isLoading} = useQuery(['users'], userService.getUsers);
    return {
        usersData: data,
        isUsersLoading: isLoading
    }
}
```

and same with products.

So now, I can write the previous example as:

```
const {usersData, isUsersLoading} = useGetUsers();
const {productsData, isProductsLoading} = useGetProducts();
```

Of course, in order to have all the keys, I iterated over all the keys provided by `useQuery` hook and customized my own custom keys with my own camel case rules, etc.

My question is, is this ok ? I mean, is this consider a good practice or just go with the `users.isLoading` logic ??

Comment: *"My question is, is this ok ?"* That question is off-topic for SO, because it calls for opinion. Instead, I'd suggest rephrasing the second half of the question so you isimply ask how you can avoid the problem.

Comment: I think that creating a custom hook just for that is a bit of an overkill; why don't you just use `const {data: usersData, isLoading: usersLoading} = useQuery(['users'], userService.getUsers);` and `const {data: productsData, isLoading: productsLoading} = useQuery(['products'], userService.getProducts);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was not intended for an opinion, rather asking for complexity issues that may arise with this pattern or just messing things up by dynamically constructing javascript keys

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find it surprising that the hook returns an object rather than an array like `useState` does, because this is **why** `useState` returns an array. (I'm not familiar with that hook; perhaps it returns a lot of things, in which case using named properties does make sense.)

You can use renaming in the destructuring:

```
const {data: users, isLoading: usersLoading} = useQuery(['users'], userService.getUsers);
const {data: products, isLoading: productsLoading} = useQuery(['products'], userService.getProducts);
```

Then use `users` and `usersLoading` for the users stuff, and `products`/`productsLoading` for the products stuff.

---

If you're going to write your own hook, I think I'd rather write a general one that returns an array:

```
function useStuff(what, how) {
    const {data, isLoading} = useQuery(what, how);
    return [data, isLoading];
}
```

Then:

```
const [users, usersLoading] = useStuff(['users'], userService.getUsers);
const [products, productsLoading] = useStuff(['products'], userService.getProducts);
```

Comment: Two questions, why did you say that that's why useState uses an array ? and second question, what about the case I want to rename all the properties in a consistent way by a custom naming rule ? (is my solution valid ? )

Comment: Ok, you just answered my first question about using array, but what about including all the properties of ```useQuery``` ?

Comment: @entropyfeverone - Again, "is my solution valid" is asking for opinion. It works, so whether you like it or not is up to you. :-) On `useState`, I'll grant you I'm making an assumption that the naming of variables is why it returns an array, but I think it's a very safe assumption.

Comment: @entropyfeverone - *"...what about including all the properties of useQuery ?"* You could always have your hook return the remaining properties in an object as a third member in the array. Or as you say, pass in a prefix and have it return an object using that prefix for its properties. There are lots of options.

Answer (score 2):

I create a custom hook where I destructure the items I need from the returned react query object, then return an array. Then you can rename them when used.

```
// Custom Hook
function useGetUsers(){
    const {data, isLoading} = useQuery(['users'], getUsers);
    return [data, isLoading]
}

function getUsers() {
    // fetch stuff
}

---

// Calling the hook

const [usersData, usersLoading] = useGetUsers()
```