# React Hooks name clash how to resolve?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I been using multiple hooks to manage my data in React and I had an issue in which that multiple hooks uses the same variable name.

```
   const { data } = useCompetitors();
   const { data } = useCompetitorGroups();
```

[image]

This results in error! What are the best practices I can do to resolve this? Using array? Or is there a way to check the naming here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use aliases to handle this case

```
const { data: data1 } = useCompetitors();
const { data: data2 } = useCompetitorGroups();
```

#### References

[Binding and assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#binding_and_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

This is a reason why most hook should return an array instead of objects. However if the hook return an object you can use renaming in the destruction:

```js
   const { data:competitior_data } = useCompetitors();
   const { data:competitior_group } = useCompetitorGroups();
```

Answer stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68133340/13150380)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to use destructuring assignment and [binding and assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#binding_and_assignment). Keep a namespace or context for the `data`.

```
const competitors = useCompetitors();
const competitorGroups = useCompetitorGroups();

// ...
console.log(competitors.data);
console.log(competitorGroups.data);
```